# jquery id selector not returning proper object

Tags: jquery, web2py

I'm trying to get a form (provided in HTML form from a callback) after adding it to already present content. Adding it presents no issues and the form shows up properly. It is provided (as HTML) by the callback with the id= (placeid + "commentinput") and added to the page. However, trying to do $(placeid + "commentinput") does not return a proper jQuery element (for example, the alert(form.tagName) is supposed to return "FORM" but is always undefined instead).

```
function click_comment1(urlstr, id) { $.ajax({url: urlstr,success: success_on_get_form(urlstr, id)}); }
function success_on_get_form(urlstr, placeid) {
return function (val) {
    $("#" + placeid + "newcomment").html(val.replace("comments_body","body"));
    $("#pup").html($("#" + placeid + "comments").html());
    var form = jQuery("#" + placeid + "commentinput");
    var func = submit_comment(urlstr, placeid);
    alert(form.id);
    form.bind('submit',func);
} }
```

I've tried every other form of selection I know of at this point (basically, .children(). I'm new to jQuery). I've been hacking at this problem in various forms helplessly for 4 hours now. I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="1commentinput" method="post">...</form>
```

This is the return from the callback; the middle part is omitted for space.

The #pup element seen is a popup as provided with [this](http://nicolashoening.de/?twocents&nr=8).

"#" + placeid + "newcomment" is a div within "#" + placeid + "comments". These first 2 calls executing seemingly properly and render the callback provided form in the popup as desired.

The intent with all of this is to add a form to this popup, which is then used to make a second callback.

Comment: I added as much as I hoped would help; I'm using web2py, so HTML is largely handled in Python helper methods. Not sure what else to add...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem most likely boils down to the fact that you are using invalid character to start your element ID..

Change it to start with a valid character and it should work.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Unfortunately, I adjusted the names of all the elements (moved the placeid to the right end) and the problem was not affected.

Comment: Okay, followup, silly question I'm sure, the form you are adding to the DOM isn't nested in another form is it?

Comment: Nothing like that, no, but, now that I think about it, the first html(...) call adds #commentinputx to the DOM once and the #pup.html(...) call adds it a second time. Could this be the cause?

Comment: @user483722 Not generally it should resolve at least one element with the proper Id, can you put up a jsfiddle with relevant pseudo-interaction?

Comment: I feel silly... There is no .id attribute? Apparently, you have to get it through .attr("id"). The things returned were correct and exactly what I needed, I just kept referencing them wrong in various ways. Thanks for your help, jsfiddle actually helped me debug it a ton. It probably was the incorrect naming which caused the issue in the beginning and my poor troubleshooting caused more issues.

Comment: Maybe. jQuery is still confusing me. In any case, I figured out the problem I was having.